# HTML attribute which excludes this value

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
" <input type="number" min="1" max="100"> *
```

...
I did not know how to exclude 0, so I set the minimum value to 1, Please help)

Comment: What do you mean by exclude? The HTML form won't allow you to submit if you've entered a number less than or equal to 0

Comment: Not getting your question correctly. Could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot exclude via html syntax, you'd need javascript for that. the min value=1 might be the only way via html only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery like that:

```js
$('input').keypress(function(e){ 
   if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
      return false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from you question you want to exclude zero, which means all other numbers (< 100) are accepted

try this code: it accepts the negative numbers + positive numbers > 0 and =< 100

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if ( e.target.value === "0" ) {
    input.value = 1
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" max="100"/>
```